# Can I use same name of App which I put on Test Flight?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I'm uploading a build on Test Flight. Later when test releases will finish. Will I be able to upload same name and information for build which I am uploading to AppStore?

Also I want to know that will I need to transfer it from Test Flight to AppStore or I have to put a separate build to for AppStore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to upload separately. You can use the same build which you are testing in TestFlight.

Test the build (TestFlight), then release it (AppStore).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use same name which you use it for TestFlight. 
You have to upload seperate build for the AppStore.